# What is /cdn-cgi/pe/bag2?

Tags: cloudflare

I'm working on minimizing my site and I'm seeing that `bag2` appears 5 times in my files waterfall. My site takes 1.6 seconds to load but one `bag2` file takes 800 seconds to load, although it's size is only 7.0 kb.

What are these bag2 files and how can I remove them to make my website faster? I like Cloudflare's anti-DDOS protection, but I'm annoyed with the rest of it.

Comment: https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/reference/cdn-cgi-endpoint/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are a part of CloudFlare's "Rocket Loader" feature. If you disable that feature, it should disable serving the bag files from cdn-cgi.